# Which Edition of ECMA-262 Does Google Apps Script Support?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, ecma

According to [this thread](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/apps-script/ecma-262/apps-script/poDhzsvZWHU/iKmrgsNCOToJ) from the old Google Group, Apps Script is based on ECMA-262 3rd Edition.

This would seem to be supported by the fact that auto-completion in the editor displays 3rd Edition array functions.

However the following code runs perfectly well, which casts doubt on the matter:

```
var array = [
  1,2,3,4,5
];

Logger.log("forEach:");
array.forEach(function (item,idx,arr) {
  Logger.log(item); 
});
```

Note the use of ECMA-262 5th Edition Array function forEach.

Would someone authoritative mind giving a definitive answer on why this is the case? And whether it's safe to rely on all 5th Edition features or a sub-set that have been implemented and seem to work?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features) says that the old runtime is based on Mozilla's Rhino JavaScript interpreter which provides a subset of [ECMAScript 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) and is based on 1.6, with a smattering of 1.7 and 1.8.

The new Apps Script runtime is supported by the [V8 runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime) with few exceptions like E6 Modules.

Comment: As of February 2020 Apps Script supports V8 runtime and "modern ECMAScript features": https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#modern_javascript_features

Answer (score 2):

From [Built-in Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services)

> Apps Script supports two JavaScript runtimes: the modern [V8](https://v8.dev/) runtime and an older one powered by [Mozilla's Rhino JavaScript interpreter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino).
>
> The [V8 runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime) supports modern [ECMAScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) syntax and features. The Rhino runtime is based on the older [JavaScript 1.6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.6) standard, plus a few features from [1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7) and [1.8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.8). You can freely choose which runtime to use with your script, but the V8 runtime is strongly recommended.