# Are javascript objects "open" like Ruby?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In Ruby, I can add and modify functionality of any class, object, or method using the same syntax I would to declare my own because Ruby has "open classes".

Is javascript like that?

.

As an example...

In my case, I want to change the way Google Apps Script handles URL objects so that every time I evaluate a URL object, the URL object itself makes sure it begins with a protocol :// (http:// by default).

Comment: In modern JavaScript runtimes it's possible to protect object properties from being modified.

Comment: An example being `Object.defineProperty`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can modify objects freely. You can modify a particular object `Object.overridenProperty = ...`, or modify all objects derived from a given *class* via its `prototype` property `Object.prototype.inheritedMethod = ...`.

Have in mind that redefining a method can be tricky, as the new definition won't share the same scope as the original definition:

```
var BaseClass;

(function(){
    var defaults = { ... };

    BaseClass = function(){
        this.someValue = defaults.someValue;
    };
}());
```

It could also happen that the *class definition* lies inside a closure and you have no practical way to override a method or property as it is generated JIT. In that case you'd need to override the property at each object you are interested in individually:

```
(function(){
    var defaults = { ... },
    BaseObject = (function(){
        var obj = function(){
            this.someValue = defaults.someValue;
        };

        return obj;
    }());
}());
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

With the caveat that how you define a "class" is pretty different than in Ruby.  But you can achieve the same effect.

This ruby:

```
#ruby
class Foo
  # no methods yet
end

foo = Foo.new

class Foo
  def bar
    'bar'
  end
end

foo.bar #=> 'bar'
```

Would have this equivalent JavaScript implementation:

```
// js
var Foo = function() {};

var foo = new Foo();

Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
  return 'bar';
};

foo.bar(); // 'bar'
```

---

You can even override things just as easily:

```
var oldBar = Foo.prototype.bar;
Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
  return "Called oldBar and got: "+ oldBar.call(this);
};

foo.bar(); // "Called oldBar and got: bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

see this class with getter and setter:

```
function User(){
this._name = "";
}
User.prototype.setName = function(name){this._name = name;}
User.prototype.getName = function(){return this._name;}
user = new User();
user.setName("somename");
alert(user.getName(););
```

[JSfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/moathhowari/phZ5x/)

Answer (score 1):

You've specifically mentioned Google Apps Script in your question. Since GAS is a [variant of JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17266648/1677912), the "usual methods" of object definition and extension apply, as covered in the other answers.

However, there's one terribly annoying exception: **You cannot extend prototypes of Google's Classes.** You can find comments about this on the issue tracker, [Issue 708](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=708). It's been marked "Won't Fix".