# Is there a way to run two functions at the same time(simultaneously/asynchrounously) with one function as an infinite loop?

Tags: function, asynchronous, google-apps-script, infinite-loop, simultaneous

I have two functions that I want to run at the same time but I can't just let them run separately as one function contains an infinite loop `while(true)`. And the problem with JavaScript is that if you where to run two functions, it will finish running the function before running the next one; so if I run a function with a `while(true)` loop, it will never move onto the next function.
If you still don't understand, here is my code:

```
function onOpen(){           // Google Apps Script trigger
    infLoop()                //how to run both of these functions at the same time?
    runScript()
}

function infLoop(){          //inf loop.

    while(True){
        Utilities.sleep(100)
        DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
        .setname("dont change this name")
    }
}

function runScript(){
    //code...
}
```

Comment: Why? Use case`````````````````​`````````````````

Comment: Apps Script has a maximum script runtime limit https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas, which will not allow you to run an infinite loop. As a workaround I suggest you to set-up a time-based trigger that will allow you to run your function in intervals of your choice: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: For example, is this GAS library useful for your situation? https://github.com/tanaikech/RunAll

Comment: Another option would be gasThreader. See: https://sites.google.com/a/mcpher.com/share/Home/excelquirks/gasthreader and https://github.com/brucemcpherson/gasThreader

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Google apps script executes synchronously. For the most part, simultaneous/paralell processing is not possible. Based on your script, it seems you want two functions to run simultaneously onOpen.  Possible workarounds(Some not tested):

#### Workaround#1: *Use Different projects*

- Create a new project: In the editor(*Legacy/Old editor only*)>File>New>Project
- First project's `onOpen()` will run `infLoop()`
- Second project's `onOpen()` will run `runScript()`
- Both functions will run simultaneously on open.

#### Workaround#2: *Simple and Installable trigger*[<sup>1</sup>](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/88f7fd5ed14da5e9afde18310da61cb5)

- Create a installable trigger for  `runScript()`
- Simple trigger `onOpen()` will run `infLoop()`
- Both functions will run simultaneously on open.
- You could use two installable triggers instead of simple and installable trigger.

#### Workaround#3: *Web apps: Call from client*

- If there is a sidebar open or if a sheet is opened from web app, it is possible to call server functions repeatedly through `google.script.run`(which run asynchrously)
- Here It is possible to run a function for 6 minutes(current runtime). But by repeatedly calling the server function, you can run the function for a long time(upto 90minutes/day = current trigger runtime quota/day)

#### Workaround#4: *Web apps: UrlFetchApp#fetchAll*[<sup>2</sup>](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/c0f383034045ab63c19604139ecb0728)

- UrlFetchApp#fetchAll runs asynchronously
- Once a web app is published, the published url can be used with query parameters. If a function name is sent as a parameter and `doGet()` executes the function, `.fetchAll` can be used to multiple functions asynchronously.

#### Workaround#5: *onEdit/onChange*

- If a edit is made, both functions(onEdit/onChange) run simultaneously.

#### Workaround#6: *Sheets API/onChange*

- If a add-on/script makes a change through sheets api, `onChange` *may* get  triggered. If triggered, every change made through sheets api causes onChange to run asynchronously.

Comment: Thank you!!! This helped a lot! I can see why you are "TheMaster".

Though is there a way to make an infinite loop while avoiding the Script Timeout?

Comment: @Mr.pizza Quotas will apply. There were talks about extending quotas to 30mins with v8. But it's in alpha stage currently.  It might come by end of this year. Until then, I don't see hope.One way would be to use to time triggers every 6 minutes.. even then you're limited to a total quota of 90 minutes/day.

Comment: Thank you! I am using the time triggers like you have suggested.

Comment: With regards to Workaround 4, you can use @Tanaike's excellent library with webapps but also without! The options are "Parallel processing with Web Apps" or "Parallel processing with the method of scripts.run of Google Apps Script API". https://github.com/tanaikech/RunAll

Comment: Another option would be gasThreader. See: https://sites.google.com/a/mcpher.com/share/Home/excelquirks/gasthreader and https://github.com/brucemcpherson/gasThreader

Comment: @Magne Looks like a nice library. Wish He explained the actual exploit though, which, on first look, just looks like #3, where there's a simultaneous execution limit of 30.

Comment: @TheMaster I know, I wish the same. What I found so far: "Gasthreader is a published Apps Script webapp" [1], which uses google.script.run to call it [2]. It seems to differ from Workaround #3 only in that you only need to call the web app / server once, and it will do the job of splitting the job into async parallel executions and merging the results back.

[1] https://sites.google.com/a/mcpher.com/share/Home/excelquirks/gasthreader/structure

[2] https://github.com/brucemcpherson/gasThreader/blob/5fd5b26e1b7573cfa7b9a4a2f331320249cc50df/Provoke.gs

Comment: @Magne Based on your links, It seems it's the same as #3 where the server is automatically called multiple times from the client using this library.

Answer (score 3):

To run two or more functions "at the same time" you should call each function separately. One way is to [use promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) from client side code.

Bear in mind that your server-side infinite loop eventually will cause that your script exceed the maximum execution time (6 minutes / 30 minutes depending on the account type that effective user is using).

Related

- [Using promises for mulitple queries to Google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35284498/1595451)

Comment: @StevendeSalas would say that [Promises don't actually execute asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241396/is-google-apps-script-synchronous#answer-60174689), and TheMaster would [confirm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62806366/run-function-asynchronously-in-google-apps-script/62807671#62807671).

Answer (score 1):

Running an infinite loop in Apps Script is futile, since there's [an enforced maximum execution time of 6 minutes for most scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations). When you hit that limit the script execution will be killed.

Judging from your example script, what you're attempting to do is a scheduled job to set the document name. **For that purpose, you would be better served using [a time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).**

You could then structure your script like this:

```
function onOpen() {
    // code...
}

function updateDocumentName() {
    DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().setName("dont change this name")
}
```

Then, you can [setup a time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) associated with the `updateDocumentName()` function.

One major difference to note: instead of executing the logic every 100ms, the highest frequency you can set with a time-driven trigger is once every 1 minute.

Answer (score -2):

YES! Simply put one function inside the other.

```
function EmailSummary() {
  // Modified from http://stackoverflow.com/a/22200230/1027723 .. SOURCE: https://mashe.hawksey.info/2015/07/tips-on-emailing-inline-google-charts-from-sheets-using-apps-script/
  function emailCharts(sheet_name){    // eg "SF_EMAIL"
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheet_name)
    var charts = sheet.getCharts();

    if(charts.length==0){
      MailApp.sendEmail({

...
```

Just make sure to indent correctly.