# concat JSON objects in a loop (No JQuery)

Tags: javascript, json

Update: Fixed mistakes in example code. Turned out my problem was caused by an additional 'records' in `var jsonVar = jsonVar.concat(results.records);`

How can I concat JSON objects in a loop? I can concat 2 JSON objects like this:

```
var json1 = {
 "records": [{
 "id": 28100988,
 "work_text_reviews_count": 13,
 "average_rating": "3.10"
 }, {
 "id": 10280687,
 "work_text_reviews_count": 80,
 "average_rating": "3.87"
 }]
}

var json2 = {
 "records": [{
 "id": 16135639,
 "work_text_reviews_count": 0,
 "average_rating": "0.00"
 }, {
 "id": 17978337,
 "work_text_reviews_count": 2414,
 "average_rating": "3.76"
 }, {
 "id": 360721218,
 "work_text_reviews_count": 4924,
 "average_rating": "3.98"
 }]
}


var json3 = json1.records.concat(json2.records);
```

To add a 3rd JSON object I know I can just add .concat(json3.records) 
but how can I dynamically concatenate JSON objects in a loop?

Example:
Say values.length = 5, this means 5 JSON objects need to be concatenated.

```
for (var i=0; i<values.length ; i++) {

response= UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
Utilities.sleep(1000);
var results = JSON.parse(response);

// this works now (had a typo here)
var jsonVar = jsonVar.concat(results.records); 

}
```

Comment: What (do you think) a "JSON object" is?

Comment: it looks more like an async problem, than a concat problem.

Comment: maybe you have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Comment: Sorry guys, I overlooked an error in my code. I had an extra 'records' in `var jsonVar = jsonVar.records.concat(results.records);`   This should be  `var jsonVar = jsonVar.concat(results.records);`

Comment: @dean2020 Don't put corrections in comments, edit the question and fix it. There seems to be another typo: `results = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)` should probably be `response =  ...`

Comment: Is `UrlFetchApp` an async function? Does it take a callback function?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers Barmar. async or not, my code seems to be working fine. Some discussion on 'UrlFetchApp` async/callback http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241396/is-google-apps-script-synchronous

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
var jsonVar = [];
for (var i=0; i<values.length ; i++) {

  results= UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  var results = JSON.parse(response);

  jsonVar = jsonVar.concat(results.records); 

}
```

But I am not sure if this would work because `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` seems to be asynchronous. This means the `response` is not guaranteed to be initialized to correct value if it takes more than 1000ms

Answer (score -1):

A JSON object is a Javascript object. You can dynamically set the object name

```
  for (var i=0; i<values.length ; i++) {
  json[i].records.concat(json[i + 1].records)
  }
```