# Try...catch not working as expected in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, try-catch

*[Edited to include a minimal reproducible example as suggested by [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder).]*

I'm working on a simple function using Google Apps Script that is supposed to post either *a date* or *an error string* to a spreadsheet's column. The column already has data validation rules that *reject any value that is not a valid date*. This is all well and good.

My problem is this:

I tried using a try...catch block to gracefully handle the error, and to just log the error message when a value doesn't pass the data validation. The try...catch doesn't seem to be working at all. Instead, the script throws the error and just breaks, and the log comes up empty.

Here's an updated screenshot (sorry, [Sourabh Choraria](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10713297/sourabh-choraria), for overriding your update) with the new code. Surprisingly, GAS is highlighting a line way above where the error should have occurred.

[image: Screenshot for the updated code]

*For a little bit of background, this script gets the IDs of various other spreadsheets stored in a column, gets the last updated timestamp for each spreadsheet, and posts the results in the result column.*

Here's the code I used.

```
function trackDocUpdates() {
    //Set the global variables
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var residentSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Resident Documents");
    var activeRange = residentSheet.getDataRange();
    var numRows = activeRange.getNumRows();
    var lastRevision = "No value yet.";

    //Loop through the rows of data to get the last updated timestamp of each document
    //The first data row is the 5th row of the sheet currently, hence the for loop starts at 5
    for (i = 5; i <= numRows; i++) {
        //Get the document URL from the current row. Currently the second column has the document URLs
        var docURL = residentSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
        //Extract the document's ID from the URL
            var docId = docURL.split("/")[5];
            //As long as there's a valid-looking document ID, get the last updated timestamp for the current document in the loop
            if (docId != undefined) {
                lastRevision = getLastRevision(docId);
                Logger.log(lastRevision);
            }

            else {
                lastRevision = "No document URL found";
                Logger.log(lastRevision);
            }
        //Post the last updated timestamp in the appropriate result cell
        postLastUpdatedTime(lastRevision, i, 9);
    }

    //Function to get the last updated timestamp for a given document
    function getLastRevision(docId) {
        //Try to get the last updated timestamp for the given document ID
        try {
            var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(docId);
            if (revisions.items && revisions.items.length > 0) {
                var revision = revisions.items[revisions.items.length-1];
                var lastModified = new Date(revision.modifiedDate);
                //var modifiedDateString = Utilities.formatDate(lastModified, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
                return lastModified;
            }

            else {
                return 'No revisions found.';
            }
        }
        //If the file cannot be accessed for some reason (wrong docId, lack of permissions, etc.), return an appropriate message for posting in the result cell
        catch(err) {
            return "File cannot be accessed.";
        }

    }

    //Function to post the last updated timestamp for a given document in the given result cell
    function postLastUpdatedTime(message, rowIndex, colIndex) {
        //If there's no argument is passed to colIndex, set its value to be 11
        colIndex = colIndex || 11;
        var cellToPost = residentSheet.getRange(rowIndex, colIndex);
        try {
            cellToPost.setValue(message);
            cellToPost.setNumberFormat('MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM');
        }

        catch(err) {
            Logger.log(err);
            residentSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 12).setValue(err);
        }

    }

    //Update the last refreshed time of the script in the first row of the result column
    var scriptUpdatedTime = new Date();
    postLastUpdatedTime(scriptUpdatedTime, 1);
}
```

Could anyone help me understand where I went wrong?

*PS: I don't have the liberty to remove the data validation that presented this problem in the first place, since I'm just adding a functionality to a client's existing spreadsheet.*

Comment: *"Sorry, I can't give here the full code that I was working on that originally generated this error, since it's a client's property."* No, but you can provide a [mcve] of it.

Comment: The `try`/`catch` shown above is correct. If you're still getting an actual **JavaScript** error, either it's not coming from the code within the `try` block above (likely), or GAS doesn't let you catch that error (which is **not** likely). For instance, is validation an asynchronous thing? Or is the error not thrown as a JavaScript error?

Comment: If you want to just ignore the error, it sounds like you want [`setAllowInvalid`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder.html#setAllowInvalid(Boolean)). If you can't do that, and it's not a JavaScript error but instead something Google Sheets displays to the user, I don't think you can do much about it (since if you can't do that, you probably can't use [`setHelpText`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder.html#setHelpText(String)), either).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the advice. I've included a minimal reprex now. As for the possibility of the error not being a JS one, or of the validation being asynchronous, I'm not equipped to answer that technically, since I'm relatively a beginner to Javascript itself. But from the little that I know, the validation is not likely an asynchronous process (as gathered [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31241674/10276412) as well).

I also can't use setAllowInvalid, apparently because that would mess with the existing functionality in the spreadsheet that's not in my control.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think a JavaScript error is getting raised here at all, which is why `try`/`catch` isn't working. You'll need to research how to intercept validation errors (if you can even do that). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, @T.J.Crowder. I'm working with the spreadsheet owner on a workaround simultaneously, but I really want to know why this wouldn't work in GAS. It's bugging me. :) Hopefully, I'll be able to find something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem.

This exact issue has been reported to Google (issuetracker.google.com) and they filed an internal case [1] about try/catch statements in Apps Script not handling data validation errors.

[1] https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763134#comment7

Comment: Thanks so much for this. At least now I don't have to run around looking for a solution that doesn't technically exist. It helps to know that Google Apps Script engine doesn't interpret spreadsheet errors as proper exceptions in script. The fact that Google has filed an internal case about this gives some hope, but it's been 4 years already. 

In any case, I hope that this helps people with similar problem understand this shortcoming, and code their GAS scripts accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

#### MCVE:

A proper [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
function testingSetValueToACellWithDataValidationWithRejectInput() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  try {
    for (var i = 1; i < 5; ++i) {
      var rng = sheet1.getRange(i, 1); //cell with datavalidation set to "reject input"
      rng.setValue('invalidData'); //setting invalid;
    }
    //setValue call above is cached and ignored until getValue()(alternating read/writes)/flush() is called
    /*SpreadsheetApp.flush();//Will error out                 <<<<<<line10 */
    /*sheet1.getRange(4, 1).getValue();//Will error out too   <<<<<<line11 */
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Error catched: ' + e); //happens if line 10/11 is not  commented
  }
  Logger.log('End'); //happens regardless
}
```

#### Issue:

- Error thrown on a different line instead of being thrown on the line that it is supposed to occur
- As written in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use-batch-operations), It is recommended to avoid alternating read-write calls and  that apps script caches `set*` calls.

  - The cache is written to the spreadsheet only when the cache is flushed. This happens, when

    - Calls are alternated. After a series of "write" calls, a "read" call is made or vice versa.
    - `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` is called.
    - In your case, the `setValue`(`cellToPost.setValue(message);`) call is made only when you alternated with the read call(`residentSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue()`). **That is why the error is made on the read call and not on the write call.**

#### Solution:

- Use Arrays and loops instead of `getValue()` in every line, which is really slow.
- If you must follow a inefficient and a slow method and use `try...catch` to catch the error, then you must `flush` the cache immediately:

  ```
    try {
          cellToPost.setValue(message);
          cellToPost.setNumberFormat('MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM');
          SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //Added;Flushes the cache and thus throws the error, which can be caught 
    } catch(err) {
          Logger.log(err);
          residentSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 12).setValue(err);
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57836700/)
- [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Thanks for the example of a proper MVCE. Nail on the head. I'll learn from it.

As for the two possible issues, it may be that the data validation is never thrown and hence caught by the `try...catch` block, but apart from the validation issue, my code has no other error thrown elsewhere that could stop the execution. And strangely, the highlighted error line is a `getValue()` call, which worked in every iteration before, and which is way above the line where the validation is checked.

From your example MCVE, the `getRange()` line is highlighted instead of the `setValue()' line.

Comment: `getDataRange()` shouldn't be a problem as well, since my loop makes sure that it iterates within valid range only.

But yes, I agree with your suggestion that I should use Arrays and loops instead of using `getValue()' over and over. That's more optimal. Appreciate the advice.

Comment: @Karthik I'm saying error is somewhere else. In my mcve, if I don't call `undeclaredFunction`, I don't get a error. Try catch block is not catching the error, but  the error is never thrown and execution continues, which means you have a error somewhere else.

Comment: I rechecked my code with your clarification in mind, but I don't see an error elsewhere. It is pretty much the data validation itself that seems to be stopping the script execution. Just to be clear, the script execution does not continue after the data validation rejects the first invalid input. The execution would probably continue if the data validation is set to just issue a warning instead of rejecting the input altogether.

Comment: @Kathik I don't agree with your conclusion. Could you try adding a try.. catch block over the actual error line: line 13 and see what it catches? Also add `Logger.log(i)` just after the for-loop's ``{``.  Also declare `i`: `var i=5`. Also, Could you give a basic structure of the document? What's in Col2, Col11 and so on?

Comment: Sure, I wrapped line 13 within a `try` block and logged the error from the `catch` block, and here's [the result](https://pastebin.com/UV07wTjB). The script executes till completion this time, but the exception thrown is the one that should be originating from data validation. As for i, 74th is the last row in my whole sheet. I even tried logging a string outside the for loop (after it), and it logs just fine after i=74.0. Col2 has the spreadsheet URLs that need to be tracked, Col9 is where I post results, and (Col11,Row1) is where I post the last executed time for reference.

Comment: @Karthik In the catch block, try `Logger.log(docURL)` to confirm that the url is retrieved properly and in the next function's catch block, use a proper error message: `}catch(err){return "File cannot be accessed because: " + JSON.stringify(err) }`

Comment: Done. Here's [the result](https://pastebin.com/erCrMyty). The `docURL`'s value gets stuck with the first URL the script cannot fetch (for lack of permissions), and it seems to keep trying for the same URL for the rest of the iterations. The `getValue()` call to the `docURL`'s cell never gets executed from this point. The reason for not being able to fetch the document comes back to data validation error. The iterator works fine.